# Modifying post titles on pages, archives and single but not dashboard/admin

Tags: plugins

Based on conversations found here, the following code (packaged in a simple  plugin that has no other code) should work to prepend to titles when displayed on pages, category archives and single post displays but not effect the view in the dashboard (such as all posts or all pages view).

```
function before_title( $title ) {
 if (!is_admin() && in_the_loop() && ( is_single() || is_page() || is_home() || is_category() ) ) {
    $postcats = get_the_category();
    if (!empty($postcats)) {
        $postcat = $postcats[0]->name;
            switch ($postcat) {
            case 'WEB':
                $title = '<span class="smalltitle">WEB</span> ' . $title;
                break;
            case 'WORD':
                $title = '<span class="smalltitle">WORD</span> ' . $title;
                break;
            case 'WORK':
                $title = '<span class="smalltitle">WORK</span> ' . $title;
                break;
            case 'WATCH/WITNESS':
                $title = '<span class="smalltitle">WATCH/WITNESS </span>' . $title;
                break;
            default:
                $title =  $title;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'before_title');
```

It works on the home page, category, single page, etc...but all the entries in the dashboard show `(no title)` -- though the proper title is there when I edit that post or page (and reappears if I comment out the code or stop the plugin).

What do I need to do to not have this code effect my dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `return $title;` one line lower. You are not returning anything for administration.